# User Prism Library With WPF, DataTrigger can not be triggered in ItemContainerStyle. Any Suggestion to get Instance of ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In MVVM pattern without Prism Library with WPF , view model is injected in manually. DataTrigger Path can be specified by

`Path=DataContext.ColumnColorSlideStatus}"`. It works fine.

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>


<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, **Path=DataContext.ColumnColorSlideStatus}"** 
                                     Value="Review">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding
                                        Converter="{StaticResource ColumnBackGroundColorConverter}"
                                        ConverterParameter="Review"
                                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, **Path=DataContext.ColumnColorSlideStatus}"**
                                     Value="NFR">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding
                                        Converter="{StaticResource ColumnBackGroundColorConverter}"
                                        ConverterParameter="NFR"
                                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

When Using Prism Library with WPF, the view and viewmodel is linked automatically by code below.

```
 xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

There is no instance of DataContext in View Xaml Code. the DataTrigger Path can not be specified to the DataContext.ColumnColorSlideStatus. DataTrigger can not be triggered.

````
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, **Path=ColumnColorSlideStatus}"** 
                                     Value="Review">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding
                                        Converter="{StaticResource ColumnBackGroundColorConverter}"
                                        ConverterParameter="Review"
                                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, **Path=ColumnColorSlideStatus}"** 
                                     Value="NFR">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding
                                        Converter="{StaticResource ColumnBackGroundColorConverter}"
                                        ConverterParameter="NFR"
                                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Is any suggestions to get instance of viewmodel into view when Prism Library is used or some way works around it
````

Comment: `the DataTrigger Path can not be specified to the DataContext.ColumnColorSlideStatus` why that? Can you expand on the "can not" part? What prevents you from doing so?

Comment: WPF Prism Library locate view and viewmodel by name. For example Mailview and Mailviewmodel, Prism Library look up postfix of view and viewmodel  of Mailview and Mailviewmodel.  It automatic link view and view model together.     For normal WPF MVVM without using Prism it has <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

Comment: sure, but why shouldn't you be able to write `Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=ColumnColorSlideStatus}"` while using the view model locator? Do you get any exception or compiler error? If so, the question would benefit from the exact wording.

Comment: by the code above Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=ColumnColorSlideStatus}" i do not get any exception. it does not work, I am trying to find a way to trigger DataTrigger in ListviewItem from viewmodel in Prism

Comment: Is your data context actually set to something? Is your window called `View` or have you modified the naming convention of the view model locator or have you registered the pair of view and view model?

Comment: i have set view and viewmodel registered. In my application i have 40 or more binding from view to viewmodel. they all work fine. Only this instance does not work.

Comment: I have made an MVVM application without Prism for testing,   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.ColumnColorSlideStatus}" .
                                     Value="Review">.  It only works by specify path to viewmodel.  I suspect that this DataTrigger Binding is in ListView logic tree. It is the reason it need to specify path to viewmodel.

Comment: for specifying the path to the view model, i.e. the data context, is does not matter whether the data context is set by xaml or attached behavior, does it?

Comment: you are right,  i figured it out, in xaml code. it does not have dataContext, but it is set by Prism in the background. I still can access DataContext in the view